# Tags on profile are showing empty results

Tags: support, bug, tags, android-app

**UPDATE STATUS** - Has been 2 months and still no answer regards to this.

---

So, the title says it all, I've tried to see my answers for a certain tag while using the SE app but the results came empty.

I even tried a few other tags, same outcome.

Here is a Screenshot of the issue:

[image]

---

**And same link/page on desktop:**

[image]

Comment: I would love to know why this was downvoted... anyway

Comment: Different tabs: `newest` and `relevance` - does it matter?

Comment: @Qwertiy same thing,  isn't relevant

Comment: Known bug, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273339/users-top-tags-in-the-profile-lead-to-a-search-query-with-no-results-in-the-and and also the link in the answer.

Comment: @JonasCz so only Q no A? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Indeed, no answers, only questions. It doesn't make sense to me either..